# Is it possible to get a PayPal Sandbox account without creating a PayPal account?

Tags: paypal

Recently PayPal changed their Sandbox account section. Now it asks for a real PayPal account to get into the Sandbox account. As I don't have a PayPal account, is there any way to get back into my Sandbox account without creating a PayPal account? Or are there any demo accounts available?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [FAQ](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support/faq#existing-sb-users), it appears as though that they require you to tie an "existing" PayPal account to an existing Developer account.

The alternative is to create a new Developer account, but you would not be able to tie your old one to this.